# Track links outsourcing tech support to Stack Overflow and provide interstitial page to visitors

Tags: feature-request

I've seen periodic notes where someone complained about a large volume of junk questions about technology or offerings, and after googling found some company or project announcement saying, "We're discontinuing technical support; follow this link to Stack Overflow to get the help you expected from our forum."

It should be possible to either automatically or manually create an alert of "There's a significantly possible spike in technology X, and [if available] the referrer is from one site or possibly URL." and after that, make a customized landing page or something for people visiting from that URL.

I don't know what the costs or downside surrounding this would be, but I've gotten the impression that moderators, who have enough to do, spend time coping with another organization's "outsource tech support to Stack Exchange for free" optimizations.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure an automated response is necessary here in these scenarios, since it happens infrequently enough (in general) that it's not really a problem.

The main thing that I've seen community members do is report the issue on Meta, and official Stack Overflow employees reach out to the company and clarify the appropriate way to go about doing something like that.

Employees that deal specifically with this do this as part of their daily job; it's not that I don't think that they could do with something (anything) to make it easier, but I don't see much value in this.

Comment: Stack Overflow's system is all about automatization, though. Tracking  referrers that generate a significant amount of questions that get closed as off-topic, and showing an interstitial to visitors that come from one of those referrers, might not be a stupid idea at all.